# D3, Scale How to set the scale?

Tags: d3.js

```
var scale = d3.scale.threshold().domain([100]).range([0,100])
```

I have data where 100 means "good" and anything below means "bad"

I want to set a d3 scale so that 100 -> 1 and anything below is -> 0

I'm not sure how to do that:

I read here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear

about this example:

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([-1, 0, 1])
.range(["red", "white", "green"]);
```

but I'm not sure about how I can apply it because my domain is continuos 0->100 but I want my range to be 0, 1 values

**EDIT:** 
This worked for me.

```
var scale = d3.scale.threshold().domain([100]).range([0,100])

console.log(scale(1)) //returns 0
console.log(scale(99.9)) //returns 0
console.log(scale(88.9)) //returns 0
console.log(scale(100)) //returns 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a filter to separate the data when styling it:

```
d3.selection().filter( function(d) { return d === 100}).attr("class", "green");
d3.selection().filter( function(d) { return d < 100}).attr("class", "red");
```

Edit: Documentation on quantized and threshold scales [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales).

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently testing with the threshold scale, I can't use the filters because I'm using the cubism.js library

Comment: That's the perfect tool. So for your previous example you could do `var scale = d3.scale.threshold().domain([100]).range(["green", "red"])`. That will send anything below 100 to red, and everything above to green.